# Error long int exceeds XML-RPC limits

Tags: php, xml-rpc

Estoy usando XML-RPC API y PHP para traer llamadas, pero me esta mandando un error cuando quiero traer las llamadas del 1er de Septiembre. Realice una prueba trayendo las llamadas de meses anteriores y me traen las llamadas sin ningún error.
Les anexo mi código cuando traigo las llamadas del mes anterior a septiembre y cuando lo intento con el mes de septiembre.

El error es:

> xmlrpcresp Object ( [val] => 0 [valtyp] => [errno] => 1 [errstr] => :long int exceeds XML-RPC limits [payload] => [hdrs] => Array ( [date] => Thu, 10 Sep 2020 15:00:40 GMT [server] => Apache/2.4.35 (FreeBSD) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-freebsd mod_wsgi/4.6.4 Python/2.7 [vary] => Accept-Encoding [content-encoding] => gzip [connection] => close [transfer-encoding] => chunked [content-type] => text/xml ) [_cookies] => Array ( ) [content_type] => text/xml [raw_data] => HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized Date: Thu, 10 Sep 2020 15:00:39 GMT Server: Apache/2.4.35 (FreeBSD) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-freebsd mod_wsgi/4.6.4 Python/2.7 WWW-Authenticate: Digest nonce="428d17936559aa8f4860fe97506b52c9", opaque="dfda091267fdb9621104d6e5fc5cb221", realm="XML API", qop="auth" Vary: Accept-Encoding Content-Encoding: gzip Connection: close Transfer-Encoding: chunked Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Thu, 10 Sep 2020 15:00:40 GMT Server: Apache/2.4.35 (FreeBSD) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-freebsd mod_wsgi/4.6.4 Python/2.7 Vary: Accept-Encoding Content-Encoding: gzip Connection: close Transfer-Encoding: chunked Content-Type: text/xml faultCode 1 faultString <type 'exceptions.OverflowError'>:long int exceeds XML-RPC limits )***

Llamadas de mes Abril 09 2020 (Si trae las llamadas)

```
function get_llamadas(){

        $params = array(new xmlrpcval(array(
            "i_account"          => new xmlrpcval(2893, "int"),
            "start_date"          => new xmlrpcval("05:00:00.000 GMT Thu Apr 09 2020", "string"),
            "end_date"          => new xmlrpcval("05:00:00.000 GMT Fri Apr 10 2020", "string")
        ), 'struct'));

        $msg = new xmlrpcmsg('getAccountCDRs', $params);

        /* replace here URL  and credentials to access to the API */
        $cli = new xmlrpc_client('https://sip.hola.net.mx/xmlapi/xmlapi');
        $cli->setSSLVerifyPeer(false);
        $cli->setSSLVerifyHost(false);
        $cli->setCredentials('usuario', 'pass', CURLAUTH_DIGEST);

        $r = $cli->send($msg);       /* 20 seconds timeout */
        // Saber el tamaño del Array
        $array_size = sizeof($r->val->me['struct']['cdrs']->me['array']);
        echo("Troncal: 2893</br>");
        echo("Cantidad llamadas: ".$array_size."</br>");
        if ($r->faultCode([me])) {
          error_log("Fault. Code: " . $r->faultCode() . ", Reason: " . $r->faultString());
          return false;
        } else {
            $contador_llamadas = 0;

            for ($i=0; $i < $array_size; $i++) {
                // Guarda el dato obtenido de la plataforma de Servnet
                $prefix = $r->val->me['struct']['cdrs']->me['array'][$i]->me['struct']['prefix']->me[string];

                if ($prefix !== "onnet_in") {

                    $contador_llamadas = $contador_llamadas+1;
                }
            }
            echo("Total llamadas salientes: ".$contador_llamadas);
        }
}
```

Llamadas de mes Septiembre 01 2020 (No trae llamadas y marca el error)

```
function get_llamadas(){

        $params = array(new xmlrpcval(array(
            "i_account"          => new xmlrpcval(2893, "int"),
            "start_date"          => new xmlrpcval("05:00:00.000 GMT Tue Sep 01 2020", "string"),
            "end_date"          => new xmlrpcval("05:00:00.000 GMT Wed Sep 02 2020", "string")
        ), 'struct'));

        $msg = new xmlrpcmsg('getAccountCDRs', $params);

        /* replace here URL  and credentials to access to the API */
        $cli = new xmlrpc_client('https://sip.hola.net.mx/xmlapi/xmlapi');
        $cli->setSSLVerifyPeer(false);
        $cli->setSSLVerifyHost(false);
        $cli->setCredentials('usuario', 'pass', CURLAUTH_DIGEST);

        $r = $cli->send($msg);       /* 20 seconds timeout */
        // Saber el tamaño del Array
        $array_size = sizeof($r->val->me['struct']['cdrs']->me['array']);
        echo("Troncal: 2893</br>");
        echo("Cantidad llamadas: ".$array_size."</br>");
        if ($r->faultCode([me])) {
          error_log("Fault. Code: " . $r->faultCode() . ", Reason: " . $r->faultString());
          return false;
        } else {
            $contador_llamadas = 0;

            for ($i=0; $i < $array_size; $i++) {
                // Guarda el dato obtenido de la plataforma de Servnet
                $prefix = $r->val->me['struct']['cdrs']->me['array'][$i]->me['struct']['prefix']->me[string];

                if ($prefix !== "onnet_in") {

                    $contador_llamadas = $contador_llamadas+1;
                }
            }
            echo("Total llamadas salientes: ".$contador_llamadas);
        }
}
```

Espero que me puedan apoyar.

Saludos y bonito jueves.

Comment: Parece ser un error de la _API_ y lo recomendable es contactar al servicio de soporte.

Comment: Hola @Triby, si esta algo raro ya que seguí realizando pruebas con más números i_account, algunos me marcan ese error y otros simplemente no tienen llamadas realizadas, pero con respecto a los clientes que marcan error no entiendo porque si son números existentes de clientes.
El cliente 2893 si trae las llamadas de 09 de Abril, pero si ese cliente lo corro con el 01 de Septiembre marca error.

Comment: Precisamente, si tu código funciona bien con determinados datos y falla con otros, el problema no está ahí, sino en la API y es el proveedor quien debe buscar la solución.

Comment: Ya mande correo de soporte. Oye @Triby de grande quiero ser igual de inteligente que tu.